# Concatenating element indexes with backbone JS .get model event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Having trouble using backbone JS model: `item.get(element index)`. I have a spreadsheet with 1248 line items and I do not want to have to reiterate the same code 1248 times to bring in all the data. is there any way I can concat this code and bring all element indexes into one event?

The code:

```
function showInfo(cameras) {
        var camera_view = new CameraView({ model: cameras.get(1) });

        $("#content").append( camera_view.render().el );

        var camera_view = new CameraView({ model: cameras.get(2) });

        $("#content").append( camera_view.render().el );

        var camera_view = new CameraView({ model: cameras.get(3) });

        $("#content").append( camera_view.render().el );

        etc.....all the way to 1248
      }
```

Im working with `backboneJS` and `tabletopJS` to pull data from a Google Spreadsheet on the "back-end".
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a simple for loop?

Comment: yes you can do using collection in backbone. use underscore.js each method to retrieve all object from collection one by one and render.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCYlcpfIXck  this video will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is to use `_.each` loop to iterate over the collection and render the list item for each model.

```
function showInfo(cameras) {
  var cameraView;

  cameras.each(function(model) {
    camera_view = new CameraView({
      model: model
    });
    $("#content").append(camera_view.render().el);
  });
}
```

Also since you are trying to render close to 1200 views, you will be manipulating the `DOM` to inject the HTML on every single iteration. Instead store the `HTML` in a separate variable and inject in one shot to reduce the manipulation to the `DOM`

```
function showInfo(cameras) {
  var cameraView;
  var $content = $("#content");
  var html = '';

  $content.empty();

  cameras.each(function(model) {
    camera_view = new CameraView({
      model: model
    });
    html += camera_view.render().el
  });
  $content.append(html);
}
```

Comment: example 1 seems to work great! thank you so much for your help!